# Wrong file selection

Tags: file-management

I have a Galaxy Tab Pro SM-T900.  When I try to select a file (JPG) from the my files.  I get the wrong file.  Is there some setting change that would fix this.

Comment: Do you truly get the wrong file, or is the file trying to be opened up by the wrong application; IE: a picture file being opened by a music app?